# Synergis Weboffice vs Geocortex Essentials?

Tags: geocortex

What are the main differences between Synergis Weboffice and Geocortex Essentials?

I know they are both used for creating web-based mapping application for end users and they depend on ArcGIS server for working but are there any differences between the tools and features they provide?

Comment: I just tried to google 'Syngergis Weboffice' and I got no hits - can you edit your Question to include a link to the software you are asking about, please?

Comment: I think Synergis is misspelled, first hit on Google: [Synergis WebOffice](http://weboffice.en.mysynergis.com/).  Also, when I've been evaluating products in the past, I've actually asked the vendors for comparisons with their competitors. Most are happy to provide that since it gives them a chance to point out their product's features. You may want to give that a try as well if you can.

Comment: Sorry I misspelled Synergis 
@EvilGenius that is a great suggestion I will try it

Comment: @AMANDA Were you able to find information about the main differences between Synergis Weboffice and Geocortex Essentials? Could you share this informations as an answer here?

Answer (score -1):

Actually, both products are great and do have their strentgh!
At the end of the day it's about the details and we're seeing a tedency within direct client comparismanets.
Have a look into the following intro:
WebOffice – an easy to administer WEB GIS application framework for ArcGIS Server to publish enterprise data via the intranet or internet including multi-language support, user management (SSO), customized queries, editing, printing and reporting, etc.
This product brings the power of a desktop GIS product into your web Browser.  It’s an open and extendable architecture which is fully controlled by the customer by having an administration tool for customization available (configuration instead of programming). - http://weboffice.en.mysynergis.com

WebOffice videos: http://weboffice.en.mysynergis.com/video/